# Kotlin - Issue in Method Parameters for requestLocationUpdates() method

Tags: android, kotlin, location, locationmanager

I am getting location from NETWORK_PROVIDER as below :

```
if(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
            {
                val locationManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

                // Define a listener that responds to location updates
                val locationListener = object : LocationListener {

                    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                        if (location != null) {
                            lastLocation = location
                            currentLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)


                            if (currentLatLng != null &&
                                currentLatLng.latitude != null &&
                                currentLatLng.longitude != null
                            ) {

                                sharedPreferenceManager?.setStringData(
                                    Constant.PrefKey.userLatitude,
                                    "" + currentLatLng.latitude
                                )

                                sharedPreferenceManager?.setStringData(
                                    Constant.PrefKey.userLongitude,
                                    "" + currentLatLng.longitude
                                )

                                getAddress(currentLatLng)
                            }
                        }else{
                            ToastUtil.displayLongDurationToast(mContext,"Could not get Location. Please turn on GPS and try again.")
                            getAndSaveCurrentLocation()
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0L, 0f,locationListener)
```

But, at the last line for the method **requestLocationUpdates** am getting the error as :

> None of the following function can be called with the arguments
>   supplied

What might be the issue ?
I have already passed valid parameters.

**EDIT**:
Getting error for the arguments at this line :

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0L, 0f,locationListener)
```

Comment: Use the debug point and try with that. Might be one of the condition is wrong and did not go next.

Comment: @PranavPatel It's argument issue at the last line. Edited please check

Comment: Can you add an error here? I guess it should be nullPointerException for a listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are importing wrong LocationListener. 
You are probably using **com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener**

but you need to import **android.location.LocationListener**

Check your import and change the import to correct LocationListener and the call should work.